# Moving from SQL 2005 [SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS] to 2008 - will I lose any features by using 'backwards compatibility'

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, collation

We're moving from SQL 2005 [Instance and DB have collation of `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`]  to SQL 2008 [which defaults to `Latin1_General_CI_AS`].

I completed a SQL 2008 R2 installation, and used default `Latin1_General_CI_AS` collation, with the restoration of the database still on `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. The excepted problems occurred - the #temp tables where in  `Latin1_General_CI_AS` whilst the db was in  `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` and this is where I am now - I need advice on the pitfalls now please.

On installation of SQL 2008 R2, I have the option on installation to use `'SQL Collation, used for backwards compatibility'` where I have the option to select the same collation as the 2005 database : `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

1. This will allow me to not have problems with #temp tables, but are there pitfalls?
2. Would I lose any functionality or features of any kind by not using a "current" collation of SQL 2008?
3. What about when we move (e.g. in 2 years ) from 2008 to SQL 2012? Will I have problems then?
4. Would I at some point be forced to go to `Latin1_General_CI_AS`?
5. I read that some DBA's script complete the rows of complete databases, and then run the insert script into the database with the new collation - I'm very scared and wary of this - would you recommend doing this?

Comment: If you think you may get into Hekaton in SQL Server 2014, [here's something else you may want to consider reading](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/bobb/thinking-about-hekaton-then-think-about-collations/).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First of all, apologies for such a long answer, as I feel that still there is a lot of confusion when people talk about terms like collation, sort order, code page, etc.

From [BOL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx) :

> Collations in SQL Server provide **sorting rules, case, and accent sensitivity properties for your data**. Collations that are used with character data types such as char and varchar dictate the code page and corresponding characters that can be represented for that data type. Whether you are installing a new instance of SQL Server, restoring a database backup, or connecting server to client databases, it is important that you understand the locale requirements, sorting order, and case and accent sensitivity of the data that you will be working with.

This means that Collation is very important as it specifies rules on how character strings of the data are sorted and compared.

Note: More info on [COLLATIONPROPERTY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190305.aspx)

**Now Lets first understand the differences ......**

Running below T-SQL :

```
SELECT *
FROM::fn_helpcollations()
WHERE NAME IN (
        'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'
        ,'Latin1_General_CI_AS'
        )
GO

SELECT 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS' AS 'Collation'
    ,COLLATIONPROPERTY('SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', 'CodePage') AS 'CodePage'
    ,COLLATIONPROPERTY('SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', 'LCID') AS 'LCID'
    ,COLLATIONPROPERTY('SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', 'ComparisonStyle') AS 'ComparisonStyle'
    ,COLLATIONPROPERTY('SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', 'Version') AS 'Version'

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Latin1_General_CI_AS' AS 'Collation'
    ,COLLATIONPROPERTY('Latin1_General_CI_AS', 'CodePage') AS 'CodePage'
    ,COLLATIONPROPERTY('Latin1_General_CI_AS', 'LCID') AS 'LCID'
    ,COLLATIONPROPERTY('Latin1_General_CI_AS', 'ComparisonStyle') AS 'ComparisonStyle'
    ,COLLATIONPROPERTY('Latin1_General_CI_AS', 'Version') AS 'Version'
GO
```

The results would be :

[image]

Looking at above results, the only difference is the Sort Order between the 2 collations.But that is not true, which you can see why as below :

**Test 1 :**

```
--Clean up previous query
IF OBJECT_ID('Table_Latin1_General_CI_AS') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE Table_Latin1_General_CI_AS;

IF OBJECT_ID('Table_SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE Table_SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;

-- Create a table using collation Latin1_General_CI_AS 
CREATE TABLE Table_Latin1_General_CI_AS (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
    ,Comments VARCHAR(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
    )

-- add some data to it 
INSERT INTO Table_Latin1_General_CI_AS (Comments)
VALUES ('kin_test1')

INSERT INTO Table_Latin1_General_CI_AS (Comments)
VALUES ('Kin_Tester1')

-- Create second table using collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
CREATE TABLE Table_SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
    ,Comments VARCHAR(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    )

-- add some data to it 
INSERT INTO Table_SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS (Comments)
VALUES ('kin_test1')

INSERT INTO Table_SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS (Comments)
VALUES ('Kin_Tester1')

--Now try to join both tables
SELECT *
FROM Table_Latin1_General_CI_AS LG
INNER JOIN Table_SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS SLG ON LG.Comments = SLG.Comments
GO
```

**Results of Test 1:**

```
Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 35
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.
```

From above results we can see that the we cannot directly compare values on columns with different collations, you have to use `COLLATE` to compare the column values.

**TEST 2 :**

The major difference is performance, as Erland Sommarskog points out at [this discussion on msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bfdc32d3-3d36-4d63-8d87-6ee972fd8130/on-sqllatin1generalcp1cias-sql-server-2008-default-collation).

```
--Clean up previous query
IF OBJECT_ID('Table_Latin1_General_CI_AS') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE Table_Latin1_General_CI_AS;

IF OBJECT_ID('Table_SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE Table_SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;

-- Create a table using collation Latin1_General_CI_AS 
CREATE TABLE Table_Latin1_General_CI_AS (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
    ,Comments VARCHAR(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
    )

-- add some data to it 
INSERT INTO Table_Latin1_General_CI_AS (Comments)
VALUES ('kin_test1')

INSERT INTO Table_Latin1_General_CI_AS (Comments)
VALUES ('kin_tester1')

-- Create second table using collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
CREATE TABLE Table_SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
    ,Comments VARCHAR(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    )

-- add some data to it 
INSERT INTO Table_SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS (Comments)
VALUES ('kin_test1')

INSERT INTO Table_SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS (Comments)
VALUES ('kin_tester1')
```

--- Create Indexes on both tables

```
CREATE INDEX IX_LG_Comments ON  Table_Latin1_General_CI_AS(Comments)
go
CREATE INDEX IX_SLG_Comments ON  Table_SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS(Comments)
```

--- Run the queries

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
GO
SELECT Comments FROM Table_Latin1_General_CI_AS WHERE Comments = 'kin_test1'
GO
```

--- This will have IMPLICIT Conversion

[image]

--- Run the queries

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
GO
SELECT Comments FROM Table_SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS WHERE Comments = 'kin_test1'
GO
```

--- This will **NOT** have IMPLICIT Conversion

[image]

The reason for Implicit conversion is because, I have my database & Server collation both as `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` and the table **Table_Latin1_General_CI_AS** has column **Comments** defined as `VARCHAR(50)` with **COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS**, so during the lookup SQL Server has to do an IMPLICIT conversion.

**Test 3:**

With the same set up, now we will compare the varchar columns with nvarchar values to see the changes in the execution plans.

-- run the query

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
GO
SELECT Comments FROM Table_Latin1_General_CI_AS WHERE Comments =  (SELECT N'kin_test1' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS)
GO
```

[image]

-- run the query

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
GO
SELECT Comments FROM Table_SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS WHERE Comments = N'kin_test1'
GO
```

[image]

Note that the first query is able to do Index seek but has to do Implicit conversion while the second one does an Index scan which prove to be inefficient in terms of performance when it will scan large tables.

**Conclusion :**

- All of the above tests shows that having right collation is very important for your database server instance.
- `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` is a SQL collation with the rules that allow you to sort data for unicode and non-unicode are different.
- SQL collation wont be able to use Index when comparing unicode and non-unicode data as seen in above tests that when comparing nvarchar data to varchar data, it does Index scan and not seek.
- `Latin1_General_CI_AS` is a Windows collation with the rules that allow you to sort data for unicode and non-unicode are same.
- Windows collation can still use Index (Index seek in above example) when comparing unicode and non-unicode data but you see a slight performance penalty.
- Highly recommend to read Erland Sommarskog answer + the connect items that he has pointed to.

---

> This will allow me to not have problems with #temp tables, but are there pitfalls?

See my answer above.

> Would I lose any functionality or features of any kind by not using a "current" collation of SQL 2008?

It all depends on what functionality/features you are referring to. Collation is storing and sorting of data.

> What about when we move (e.g. in 2 years ) from 2008 to SQL 2012? Will I have problems then? Would I at some point be forced to go to Latin1_General_CI_AS?

Cant vouch ! As things might change in and its always good to be inline with Microsoft's suggestion + you need to understand your data and the pitfalls that I mentioned above. Also refer to [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/357974/make-latin1-general-100-ci-as-the-default-collation-for-us-english) and [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/330736/setup-uses-outdated-default-collation) connect items.

> I read that some DBA's script complete the rows of complete databases, and then run the insert script into the database with the new collation - I'm very scared and wary of this - would you recommend doing this?

When you want to change collation, then such scripts are useful. I have found myself changing collation of databases to match server collation many times and I have some scripts that does it pretty neat. Let me know if you need it.

References :

- [Storage and Performance Effects of Unicode](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189617%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- [Working with Collations](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187582%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- [Collation and Unicode Support](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx)
- [Code Page Architecture](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186356%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what @Kin detailed in his [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/48416/30859), there are a few more things to be aware of when switching the server's (i.e. instance's) default collation (items above the horizontal line are directly relevant to the two collations mentioned in the Question; items below the horizontal line are relevant to the general):

- IF YOUR DATABASE'S DEFAULT COLLATION IS *NOT* CHANGING, then the "implicit conversion" performance issue described in @Kin's answer should *not* be a problem since string literals and local variables use the Database's default Collation, not the server's. The only impacts for the scenario in which the instance level Collation is changed but not the database level Collation are (both described in detail below):

  - potential collation conflicts with temporary tables (but not table variables).
  - potential broken code if casing of variables and/or cursors does not match their declarations (but this can only happen if moving to an instance with a binary or case-sensitive collation).
- One difference between these two Collations is in how they sort certain characters for `VARCHAR` data (this does not affect `NVARCHAR` data). The non-EBCDIC `SQL_` Collations use what is called "String Sort" for `VARCHAR` data, while all other Collations, and even `NVARCHAR` data for the non-EBCDIC `SQL_` Collations, use what is called "Word Sort". The difference is that in "Word Sort", the dash `-` and apostrophe `'` (and maybe a few other characters?) are given a very low weight and are essentially ignored unless there are no other differences in the strings. To see this behavior in action, run the following:

  ```sql
  DECLARE @Test TABLE (Col1 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL);
  INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('aa');
  INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('ac');
  INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('ah');
  INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('am');
  INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('aka');
  INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('akc');
  INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('ar');
  INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('a-f');
  INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('a_e');
  INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('a''kb');

  SELECT * FROM @Test ORDER BY [Col1] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;
  -- "String Sort" puts all punctuation ahead of letters

  SELECT * FROM @Test ORDER BY [Col1] COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS;
  -- "Word Sort" mostly ignores dash and apostrophe
  ```

  Returns:

  ```
  String Sort
  -----------
  a'kb
  a-f
  a_e
  aa
  ac
  ah
  aka
  akc
  am
  ar
  ```

  and:

  ```
  Word Sort
  ---------
  a_e
  aa
  ac
  a-f
  ah
  aka
  a'kb
  akc
  am
  ar
  ```

  While you will "lose" the "String Sort" behavior, I'm not sure that I would call that a "feature". It is a behavior that has been deemed undesirable (as evidenced by the fact that it wasn't brought forward into any of the Windows collations). However, it *is* a definite difference of behavior between the two collations (again, just for non-EBCDIC `VARCHAR` data), and you might have code and/or customer expectations based upon the "String Sort" behavior. **This requires testing your code and possibly researching to see if this change in behavior might have any negative impact on users.**
- Another difference between `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` and `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS` is the ability to do [Expansions](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/#Expansions) on `VARCHAR` data (`NVARCHAR` data can already do these for most `SQL_` Collations), such as handling `æ` as if it were `ae`:

  ```sql
  IF ('æ' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS =
      'ae' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS)
  BEGIN
    PRINT 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS';
  END;

  IF ('æ' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS =
      'ae' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS)
  BEGIN
    PRINT 'Latin1_General_100_CI_AS';
  END;
  ```

  Returns:

  ```
  Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
  ```

  The only thing you are "losing" here is *not* being able to do these expansions. Generally speaking, this is another benefit of moving to a Windows Collation. However, just like with the "String Sort" to "Word Sort" move, the same caution applies: it is a definite difference of behavior between the two collations (again, just for `VARCHAR` data), and you might have code and/or customer expectations based upon *not* having these mappings. **This requires testing your code and possibly researching to see if this change in behavior might have any negative impact on users.**

  <sup>(first noted in this S.O. answer by @Zarepheth: [Can SQL Server SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS be safely converted to Latin1_General_CI_AS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22055580/577765))</sup>
- The server-level collation is used to set the collation of the system databases, which includes `[model]`. The `[model]` database is used as a template to create new databases, which includes `[tempdb]` upon each server startup. But, even with a change of server-level collation changing the collation of `[tempdb]`, there is a somewhat easy way to correct for collation differences between the database that is "current" when `CREATE #TempTable` is executed and `[tempdb]`. When creating temporary tables, declare a collation using the `COLLATE` clause and specify a collation of `DATABASE_DEFAULT`:

  ```sql
  CREATE TABLE #Temp (Col1 NVARCHAR(40) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT);
  ```

---

- It is best to use the most recent version of the desired collation, if multiple versions are available. Starting in SQL Server 2005, a "90" series of collations was introduced, and SQL Server 2008 introduced a "100" series of collations. You can find these collations by using the following queries:

  ```sql
  SELECT * FROM sys.fn_helpcollations() WHERE [name] LIKE N'%[_]90[_]%'; -- 476

  SELECT * FROM sys.fn_helpcollations() WHERE [name] LIKE N'%[_]100[_]%'; -- 2686
  ```

  Since you are on SQL Server 2008 R2, you should use `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS` instead of `Latin1_General_CI_AS`.
- A difference between the case-sensitive versions of these particular collations (i.e. `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` and `Latin1_General_100_CS_AS` ) is in the order of upper-case and lower-case letters when doing case-sensitive sorting. This also affects single-character class ranges (i.e. `[start-end]`) that can be used with the `LIKE` operator and the `PATINDEX` function. The following three queries show this effect for both sorting and the character range.:

  ```sql
  SELECT tmp.col AS [Upper-case first]
  FROM (VALUES ('a'), ('A'), ('b'), ('B'), ('c'), ('C')) tmp(col)
  WHERE tmp.col LIKE '%[A-C]%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
  ORDER BY tmp.col COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS; -- Upper-case first

  SELECT tmp.col AS [Lower-case first]
  FROM (VALUES ('a'), ('A'), ('b'), ('B'), ('c'), ('C')) tmp(col)
  WHERE tmp.col LIKE '%[A-C]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS
  ORDER BY tmp.col COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS; -- Lower-case first

  SELECT tmp.col AS [Lower-case first]
  FROM (VALUES (N'a'), (N'A'), (N'b'), (N'B'), (N'c'), (N'C')) tmp(col)
  WHERE tmp.col LIKE N'%[A-C]%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
  ORDER BY tmp.col COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS; -- Lower-case first
  ```

  The only way to get upper-case to sort before lower-case (for the same letter) is to use one of the 31 Collations that supports that behavior, which is the `Hungarian_Technical_*` Collations and a handful of `SQL_` Collations (which only support this behavior for `VARCHAR` data).
- Less important for this particular change, but still good to know about since it would be impacting if changing the server to a binary or case-sensitive collation, is that the server level collation also affects:

  - local variable names
  - CURSOR names
  - GOTO labels
  - name resolution of the `sysname` datatype

  Meaning, if you or "the programmer who left recently" who is apparently responsible for all bad code ;-) were not careful about casing and declared a variable as `@SomethingID` but then referred to it as `@somethingId` later on, that would break if moving to a case-sensitive or binary collation. Similarly, code that uses the `sysname` datatype but refers to it as `SYSNAME`, `SysName`, or something other than all lower-case will also break if moved to an instance using a case-sensitive or binary collation.