# Unexpected Implicit conversion in a procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, performance, stored-procedures, execution-plan, query-performance

I have a procedure like this (simplified):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test @userName VARCHAR(64)
SELECT * 
FROM member M
INNER JOIN order O  
ON M.MemberId=O.MemberId
WHERE M.Username = @userName
```

There is a non-clustered index on Username column of the Member table.

Plan cache shows an Implicit Conversion as such:

> Seek Keys[1]: Prefix: [MyDatabase].[dbo].[Member].Username = Scalar
>   Operator(CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(64),[@Username],0))

I was just wondering what might be causing this implicit conversion as both the parameter and the field data type "UserName" is varchar(64)?

SP is called from framework like this:

```
EXEC test @Username=N'webSite.com'
```

Thank you.

Comment: In addition to being consistent about using N for Unicode and no N for varchar, please [always use the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix). Also, `order` is a keyword, and thus a terrible choice for a table name (and many would argue that a table of *orders* or *members* should not have singular names - this makes it seem like they will only ever contain exactly one row).

Comment: (And FWIW I was able to remove the implicit convert simply by adding OPTION (RECOMPILE) to the statement inside the procedure. I didn't have to change the collation of the table, clear the plan cache, etc.)

Comment: @Stackoverflowuser you might find [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/48416/8783) answer useful in understanding how/why collation is a very important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was all down to collation of the column. It was different from the database's (and the table's) collation. Now changed the column's collation to database's and no more implicit conversion shows up. Have no idea about the internals and why it caused the problem.

Answer (score 5):

The CONVERT_IMPLICIT is occurring because you have a collation on the column which does not match the parameter's collation.  So the parameter is converted to the column's collation.

To explain further - there are collation coercion rules which triggers this conversion.  So if you have an implicit collation for the column and a coercible-default for the parameter then the parameter is converted to the column's collation.  If both had explicit but different collations, then a collation conflict error would result.

Comment: How is this different from the highest voted answer?

Comment: The answer was incomplete and the op stated he did not know why it happened which is outlined in my response.  The issue was the difference in collation between the column and parameter.