# SQL Server ; working around collation mismatches

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, collation

Imagine the following scenario: I have two servers which are on two separate private networks.

A linked server has been created, and there is a table in server A which has an updated version of the same table on server B. The updates are not extensive, essentially just a reassignment of some Boolean values.

The connection between the two servers is reliable but relatively slow, and there is a collation mismatch between the two tables.

Is there a recommended or standard way of updating information between two servers with a collation mismatch?

Comment: In linked server property, you can set `use remote collation` to TRUE. at tsql level, you can use `collate`.

Comment: Additionally, I would like to point out [Linked Servers and Collation Compatibility](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2008/02/14/how-it-works-linked-servers-and-collation-compatibility.aspx) from CSS and [this answer to understand collation a bit more](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/48416/8783)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use the `collate` operator in the join.  Such as:

```
select <column list>
from dbo.firsttable f
join linkedserver.database.dbo.secondtable d 
   on f.name collate database_default = d.name collate database_default
```

Of course, you can also specify a specific collation, such as: `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI`

Comment: I never have had to do both sides for `collate database_default` in the past, but this works as well.  Accepting your edit.

Comment: Reminded me of a problem during my Jr. DBA days. :)